# Using Jest.js to test Adobe ExtendScript

Tags: jestjs

I want to do unit testing with my Adobe JSX files using Jest.

However, all Jest tutorials have some package.json which I don't use, and they use modules and requires which aren't in ES3 javascript, etc.

Plus 'JSX' has been appropriated by React, so it's also probably going to think I'm doing React files and not Adobe ES3 files.

Is there some way to use Jest and not bother with any modules and packages? I just want to test some ancient-style ES3 code that's just javascript.
If JSX extension is going to muddle things up, is there a way to do this with a single JS file?

Comment: As I understand it JSX came out of React, so they didn't exactly "appropriate" it. But Jest doesn't know anything about JSX, it needs e.g. Babel or TSC to transpile to code it can run.

Comment: JSX was Adobe ExtendScript before there was a Facebook.

Comment: Are you just referring to the *file extension*? Again, Jest won't do anything about JSX *syntax* (whether in .js or .jsx files), that's up to a preprocessor.

Comment: Yea just the file extension. But I see your main point is, it's got to be a TS project. That is I guess as good of an answer as can be.

Comment: It *doesn't* have to be a TS project, that's not what I said; the typescript compiler was just one example of a preprocessor that would convert JSX syntax to plain JS Jest can understand (which if you're not actually using that syntax is irrelevant to you anyway).

Comment: So if I just have a js file and I have some functions in it and wish to use Jest, is there a way to do this without creating a front-end javascript app project or what-not? Do I make a fake package.json file and put it into my folder with the one file I wish to test? (I am using VSCode and attempting to use the Jest extension in it)

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to say. A `package.json` file doesn't mean a frontend app project, just one managed by NPM (or Yarn). What would a "fake" package file even be (would it still be JSON)? If you're not using NPM you'd need to find another way to make Jest and its dependencies available. And without any module system you'd need to find a way to get those functions *out* of that file (here's [one way](https://github.com/CodeYourFuture/proctor/blob/master/tests/loadGlobals.js) I've done that, not sure I'd exactly recommend it).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226748/discussion-between-vasily-hall-and-jonrsharpe).

Comment: You can configure it to process .jsx the way you need. If you don't want it to be React JSX then don't make it so. Jest is primarily used for modular testing. It can be done with Jest but this doesn't mean it's the right tool. Probably Jasmine is.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I got some help and it was stated to me that I should install the jest with its modules in the project's directory - my global installation won't do. And, sure enough once the installation went, it worked.